# Zoom in - Zoom out problem on the Javascript Background

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, responsive

I want to apply a javascript background on my website. I found a ready one, but I recognize a problem on it. When you scrool with mouse on browser, zoom in or zoom out, it starts to look so strange. You can try it on your own from that demo link;

[Demo](https://www.cssscript.com/demo/interactive-colorful-triangle-background-with-javascript-and-canvas-triangles-js/)

Also the html and css code of this animational background is in this link;

[Link of HTML-CSS-Javascript of this demo](https://www.cssscript.com/interactive-colorful-triangle-background-with-javascript-and-canvas-triangles-js/)

Can you help me, how can I prevent it from being zoomed in or zoomed out on a browser ?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. S

Comment: I can't scroll it as it contains nothing to make it scroll.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only do it using jquery with below code,

```
$(document).keydown(function(event) {
  if (event.ctrlKey==true && (event.which == '61' || event.which == '107' || event.which == '173' || event.which == '109'  || event.which == '187'  || event.which == '189'  ) ) {
        event.preventDefault();
     }
    // 107 Num Key  +
    // 109 Num Key  -
    // 173 Min Key  hyphen/underscor Hey
    // 61 Plus key  +/= key
});

$(window).bind('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function (event) {
       if (event.ctrlKey == true) {
       event.preventDefault();
       }
});
```

**Note:** Make sure you have included jquery in your code before this script.